# cur.fetchone()[0] not subscriptable (or) local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sqlite

I've got some problems with Sqlite, trying to take a link from an SQL table[1] i used two methods ( that both failed ):
the first is showing : 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
for k in range(len(Word)): #Word is a str 
    l=Word[k]
    cur.execute("SELECT link FROM G WHERE letter=='l'")
    img = mpimg.imread(cur.fetchone()[0])
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(5)
```

and this one shows: local variable 'img' referenced before assignment

```
for k in range(len(Word)):
    l=str(Word[k])
    cur.execute("SELECT link FROM G WHERE letter=='l'")
    for e in cur:
        img = mpimg.imread(str(e[0]))
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(5)
```

and is the synthax " letter=='l' " working ? 
Thnaks for your help :)

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwACO.jpg

Comment: Please add a small script to recreate a part of your sqlite-Database. That way you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess the picture of the database will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major errors in your code.

First, in Python you should (almost) never iterate over `range(len(something))`. Just iterate over Word, which gives you the letter directly.

Secondly, you haven't passed the letter to your SQL; you're just querying against the literal value "l", which isn't in the table. You need to use parameters.

```
for l in Word:
    cur.execute("SELECT link FROM G WHERE letter==?", (l,))
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but why you wrote (l,) and we've got only one ? 
and by the way when i run the script it shows : The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: Because params should be an iterable. The other issue should be fixed, there shouldn't have been quotes around the ? placeholder.